# assigning different weights to every numpy column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following numpy array:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
import numpy as np

# NumPy array comprising associate metrics
# i.e. Open TA's, Open SR's, Open SE's
associateMetrics = np.array([[11,  28,  21],
   [27,  17,  20],
   [19,  31,  3],
   [17,  24,  17]]).astype(np.float64)
print("raw metrics=", associateMetrics)
```

Now, I want to assign different weights to every column in the above array & later normalize this. For eg. lets say i want to assign higher weight to 1st column by multiplying by 5, multiple column 2 by 3 and the last column by 2.

How do i do this in python? Sorry a bit new to python and numpy.

I have tried this for just 1 column but it wont work:

```
# Assign weights to metrics
weightedMetrics = associateMetrics
np.multiply(2, weightedMetrics[:,0])
print("weighted metrics=", weightedMetrics)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make use of numpy's [array broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html). This means that lower-dimensional arrays can be automatically expanded to perform a vectorized operation with an array of higher (but compatible) dimensions. In your specific case, you can multiply your `(4,3)`-shaped array with a 1d weight array of shape `(3,)` and obtain what you want:

```
weightedMetrics = associateMetrics * np.array([5,3,2])
```

The trick is that you can imagine numpy `ndarray`s to have leading singleton dimensions, along which broadcasting is automatic. By this I mean that your 1d numpy weight array of shape `(3,)` can be thought to have a leading singleton dimension (but only from the point of view of broadcasting!). And it's easy to see how the array of shape `(4,3)` and `(1,3)` should be multiplied: each element of the latter has to be used for full columns of the former.

In the very general case, you can even use arithmetic operations on, say, an array of shape `(3,1,3,1,4)` and one of shape `(2,3,4,4)`. What's important that dimensions that meet should either agree, or one of the arrays should have a singleton dimension at that place, and one of the arrays is allowed to be longer (in the front).

Answer (score 0):

i found my answer. This is what i used:

```
print("weighted metrics=", np.multiply([ 1,   2,   3], associateMetrics))
```